# ConvertTo-JSON not outputting correctly

Tags: json, powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to use the ConvertTo-JSON method in Powershell to create a JSON result but my output that I'm getting is not valid JSON. A sample of my output is:

```
{
    "label":  "$stockShortName"
}
{
    "label":  "$stockShortName"
}
```

This is what I'm expecting:

```
[
    {
        "label":  "$stockShortName"
    },
    {
        "label":  "$stockShortName"
    }
]
```

This is the code that I'm using:

```
#Write each message where there is a stockshortname
foreach ($row in $DataSet.Tables[0].Rows){  
    $stockShortName = $row[0].ToString().Trim()
    (New-Object PSObject |
     Add-Member -PassThru NoteProperty label '$stockShortName' ) | ConvertTo-JSON
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason for wrong results is the fact, that you pass *individual* objects to ConvertTo-Json rather than entire collection. If you want to use foreach construct:

```
$(foreach ($row in $DataSet.Tables[0].Rows){  
    $stockShortName = $row[0].ToString().Trim()
    (New-Object PSObject |
     Add-Member -PassThru NoteProperty label '$stockShortName' ) 
}) | ConvertTo-JSON
```

Note the use of subexpression (`$(code)`) - otherwise foreach won't write to the pipeline.

Comment: I am using `ConvertTo-Json` on a JSON-based REST endpoint which returns an array. The value I see is `{ "value" : [...], "count" : 5 }`, but I just want to get the value and I am not interested in getting an object with value and count. How do I do this?